# What exactly is happening when we have unnamed parameters in these functions?

Tags: c++, parameters

I was looking at an iterator class for a linked list and saw this operator overloading and didn't really understand what was going on. I was under the impression that 'int' always has to be declared with a variable name?

```
   void operator++(int)
    {
            assert(m_node != NULL);
            m_node = m_node->m_next;
    }

    void operator--(int)
    {
            assert(m_node != NULL);
            m_node = m_node->m_prev;
    }
```

Comment: If I would have to guess, I think it means that the parameter is not given a name and is thus not being used. Not sure though.

Answer (score 4):

Parameter names are always optional. However, the `int` in this case is special as it denotes this is a *postfix* operator meaning you are able to do `list++` and `list--`.

Reference: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/operators

Answer (score 4):

You can always leave out a parameter name if you want to. If you do that in a normal function definition, that means that an argument must still be provided to the function, but the function doesn't use it:

```
void f(int) // unnamed parameter
{
    // can't use the parameter without a name
}

f();   // ERROR: wants an int
f(42); // OK: takes an int (but ignores it)
```

In the case of the increment and decrement operators, an unused `int` parameter is the magic that indicates that this is the postfix operator, `x++`, not the prefix operator, `++x`, which has no parameters.

Comment: FWIW: if you write `i++`, where `i` is your iterator, `operator++(int)` will be called with an argument of `0`.  (Of course, you _could_ call `i.operator++( 42 )`.  But I can't imagine anyone doing so.)

Answer (score 2):

Because you have two ++ operators, it is a special syntax to differentiate them between post- and pre- incrementation.

```
void operator++(int)
```

means postincrementation

```
void operator++()
```

means preincrementation

So in your case, you first return, then increase.

Answer (score 1):

void operator++(int)

This means post increment operator. int is just a dummy variable to distinguish it from pre-increment operator. Compiler would pass 0 in its place when calling post increment operator.